# CSS layout - How to lay every box especially when sidebar is not staying in the container?

Tags: html, css

See the html and css : bare for now. **UPDATE** Add more css in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jbgBs/

[image]

I looked around for Google and I attempted to lay everything in position but I failed.

How to lay the boxes according to the image? I tried to use container where the banner and footer could run freely across the page width or screen. But I am stuck with container limiting the sidebar's layout. It would float right but it would be staying at the right of the container, not up to the banner position. Also how to make content stay in their width and height according to the length of content? Sidebar should stay on right up to where the banner is. The content-footer would be within the width of the content and sidebar (in other word as in the container width).

The container for header, banner text, content, content-footer and footer would limit the positioning of the sidebar.

Any insight or help would be very much appreciated. 
Thank you

**EDIT**

Next question - as far as you see my code on fiddle, I somewhat make it layout work - personally it fails. As it is urgent, I need to make sidebar stay even if the browser is resized - how?

[image]
    aside{position:absolute; top:xxx; right: xxx; z-index:10;}

However it is going through content when browser is resized.

Any idea how to make it stay on its position?

**#2 EDIT**
[image]

The footer won't stay on the bottom of the screen in IE7 - I tried Sticky footer CSS i found on google, but only IE 7 it is moved a bit more far from the screen

Comment: +1 for the clear and colorful question! I'm sure this is possible with some fiddling around. PS. Your fiddle indicates you're using HTML5, what browsers are you looking to support? (e.g. will you support <IE9 with Modernizr? or just IE9+?)

Comment: @Jeroen, supporting just IE9+ will do. I tried putting the aside outside the container and position it to absolute with top and right .. it somehow works. but the problem is that when i resize the browser, the  sidebar go through the other divs. Is it normal?

Comment: `I need to make sidebar stay even if the browser is resized - how?` - try `position:fixed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loved your visualization of this question very much, so decided to have a shot. First up, a screenshot of my suggestion:

[image]

Firefox, IE9, and Chrome render this similarly. Here's the HTML5 for it:

```
<header id="first">
    <section>Logo</section>
    <nav>/ nav</nav>
    <section>/ tagline</section>
</header>

<header id="second">
    banner will run across the website
    <section>text on banner</section>
</header>

<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="content">
        Content
    </section>
    <aside>
        Sidebar
    </aside>
    <footer>content footer</footer>
</div>

<footer>
    Footer will run across the page
    <section id="fineprint">copyright and sitemap</section>
</footer>
```

With some added CSS, partially for demo purposes only:

```
header#first                    { background-color: #C4DDFF; }
header#second                   { background-color: #F6A8FF; }
header#second section           { background-color: #FFFD3D; }

div#wrapper                     { background-color: #FFC993; }
div#wrapper section#content     { background-color: #FF6138; }
div#wrapper aside               { background-color: #74FF4A; }
div#wrapper footer              { background-color: #FFFFFF; }

body > footer                   { background-color: #EC4F4F; }
body > footer section#fineprint { background-color: #0BB5CE; }

body > header#first section
,body > header nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

header#first
,body > footer section 
,header#second section {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
}

div#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 8px;
}

div#wrapper section#content {
    float: left;
    width: 350px; 
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    min-height: 300px; /* demo purpose */
}

div#wrapper aside {
    float: right;
    width: 140px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    min-height: 200px; /* demo purpose */
}

div#wrapper footer {
    clear: both;
}

body > footer {
    clear: both;
}
```

Add some [reset css from a boilerplate](http://html5reset.org/) and you should have a decent starting point.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj7gh/) demonstrating this code. Hope it helps.

Comment: ah it helps! but it is kinda too late that I saw your post :( still thank you it would be of help in next project.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div
        {
            margin: 10px;
        }
        .main
        {
            background-color: rgb(255, 204, 153);
            width: 600px;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 450px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        .logo
        {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            height: 40px;
        }
        .content
        {
            background-color: rgb(204, 51, 0);
            width: 400px;
            height: 250px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .sidebar
        {
            background-color: rgb(0, 204, 102);
            width: 160px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 510px;
            top: 5px;
        }
        .contentFooter
        {
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 204);
            position: relative;
            height: 45px;
        }
        .bannerMain
        {
            background-color: rgb(204, 102, 255);
            height: 70px;
            width: 700px;
            left: -100px;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 90px;
        }
        .bannerText
        {
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 400px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .footerMain
        {
            background-color: rgb(204, 51, 0);
            height: 65px;
            width: 700px;
            left: -100px;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 90px;
        }
        .copyRight
        {
            background-color: rgb(0, 153, 255);
            width: 580px;
            height: 35px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="logo">
            Logo
        </div>
        <div class="bannerMain">
            Banner Run Across Website
            <div class="bannerText">
                text on Banner
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                Sidebar
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Content
        </div>
        <div class="contentFooter">
            Content Footer
        </div>
        <div class="footerMain">
            Footer Will Run Across Page
            <div class="copyRight">
                CopyRight
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbgBs/5/)

Comment: thank you for the help. But I checked fiddle and banner and footer doesn't run freely across the page/screen?

Comment: @Josephine It does within Google Chrome at least. Have you tried looking at other browsers?

Comment: @Amadiere - yes, i looked at it on Firefox and the banner/footer doesn't run across the screen.

Comment: @Josephine: did you mean to say, banner/footer are fixed at some position and doesn't scroll with the rest of the page?

Comment: @dotNETbeginner - yes it is fixed but I change it to width:100% to see if it will run across the screen/page and it doesn't help anything

Comment: @dotNETbeginner - strange. i tried it on IE and FF and they do not still run across the page, unless you change something in code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the 960 grid system.It will help you managing your div with less effort.

http://960.gs/